# Python command line arguments in class not working

Tags: python, command-line

I am accepting two strings `word1` and `word2`, through command line which should contain alphabets only.

The `check_conditions` function will make sure strings are for alphabets only.

When I run this program as `python myprogram.py 'word1' 'word2'`, it does not show anything, no error,  no output.

When I run this program without using class, it works as excepted.

```
 class FindWinner:
    def __init__(self, word1, word2):
        self.word1 = word1
        self.word2 = word2

def check_conditions(self):
    special_chars = set('[~!@#$%^&*.-()_+{}":;01234567989\']+$')
    if special_chars.intersection(self.word1) or special_chars.intersection(self.word1) or (len(self.word1) != len(self.word2) 
or ('no' in self.word1) or ('no' in self.word2)):
        print('Invalid string.')
    else:
        print("String is valid")
        print(list(self.word1))
        print(list(self.word2))


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("word1", help="First word")
    parser.add_argument("word2", help="Second word")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    c1 = FindWinner(args.number1, args.number2)
    c1.check_conditions()
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
I missed to call `main()`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, I am getting another error:

`if special_chars.intersection(self.word1) or special_chars.intersection(self.word1) or (len(self.word1) != len(self.word2) 
or ('no' in self.word1) or ('no' in self.word2)):`

When I run python `myprogram.py my_string my_long_string`, it gives me `string is valid` output(else part). As per above condition, both strings should not contain any special char & len should be same.

Comment: Are you calling `main()` anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

You should call the main function from your code since you have only defined it not called it. The usual way to get this done by adding the following lines at bottom of your code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks sdvd. It worked.
Now, I am getting another error AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'number1'

Comment: Instead of 'number1' and 'number2' use 'word1' and 'word2'

Comment: I missed to rename. Thank you very much sdvd. 
When I run python myprogram.py my_string my_long_string, it gives me string is valid output(else part). As per above condition, both strings should not contain any special char & len should be same.

Answer (score 0):

To expound on @sdvd’s answer, the lines

```
if __name__ == “__main__”:
    main()
```

Checks if the script is being invoked directly by the interpreter or if it is being imported. If the script is being imported, the main function is not run, because chances are you don’t want to run the script immediately. If the script is being called directly by the interpreter, you want to run the main function immediately, which is what happens when that expression evaluated to true.

In your script now, there is no call to the main function, so nothing happens. Add the above lines to the bottom of your script, and things should proceed as you want them to.

To access your arguments, use `args.word1` and `args.word2` instead of `args.number1` and `args.number2`because that’s what you named them.

Comment: Thanks for your input Steampunkery.
I've edited the program as suggested by sdvd.

Comment: I have zero experience using ArgParser, but a quick glance at the docs tells me that you have arguments named `word1` and `word2`. I believe that you can access them like so: `args.word1` and `args.word2`. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You name the argument one thing and use it later with another name.

Try using `args.word1` and `args.word2`, or call them `number1` and `number2` when you add them (using `add_argument`).